# Verbs in plural after a singular noun

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

These are some sentences I found in some academic books I was reading:

> A small white blob is reflected there, precisely where Beth’s
> camera-flash left behind proof of her presence as if *the daughter
> were* some insurance company adjustor routinely investigating a home
> break-in.
>
> Few inquiries into particular words end with the great Dictionary’s
> account, but even fewer could start with any confidence if *it were*
> not there.

What puzzles me is why the verb is used in plural whereas its subject is in singular. Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: This is the "irrealis were" sometimes called "subjunctive were"  There are plenty of questions about it, and it should be covered in any advanced grammar book. or in the web https://www.dailywritingtips.com/i-wish-i-were/

Comment: @JamesK thank you, I completely missed that these are in the if clause, which is indicative of the irreals.